# Как добавить готовый svg элемент на страницу?

Tags: html, css

Вопрос такой – для чего предназначены атрибуты xmlns, xmlns:xlink, и обязательно ли их указывать?
Насколько я понимаю, через эти атрибуты нельзя добавить готовый svg элемент на страницу сайта. Каким атрибутом можно это сделать (хочу добавить svg как "встроенный")

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500"> <!-- SVG code here --> </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img src='data:image/svg+xml;...` можно, как и другие картинки.

https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/